# How to use IN clause with SQLite for C?

Tags: c, sqlite

I am facing an issue with executing SQL query in C library for SQLite. 
Here issue is when query contains IN clause.

Eg.,

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID IN (?);
```

C:

```
sqlite3_stmt *elems_stmt;
char empIds[40];
...
...
...
sqlite3_bind_text(elems_stmt, 1, (const char *)empIds, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Here empIds could be **4,5,6**

But as result, elems_stmt not getting any results.

Instead, if I hard code the values in the query as

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID IN (4,5,6);
```

I am able to see the results.

Please let me know what is missing in the first query and corresponding code.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot parameterize the `IN` operator with a variable number of values. You'll need to use Dynamic SQL.

Comment: what is dynamic SQL? How to use it with c library for sqlite ?

Comment: Dynamic SQL is when you generate SQL as a string in your program dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not possible in sqLite, assuming you have a variable number of values in your `IN` statement. Instead, you can just clip together the query as a string with other program logic and then execute it like you would any hardcoded one.

Comment: Thanks. Done a workaround. Since I know the maximum number of values that can occur with IN statement, I will hard code those many place holders in the query. Assign relevant number of values and remaining will be assigned with default values. SELECT * FROM (?,?,?,?) will be assigned values (4,5,6,-1) where -1 indicating default value.